# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException The prefix "a" for element "a:IDType" is not bound in groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui, xmlslurper

I am trying to replace some node in my existing soap envelope using groovy script in SOAPUI tool
Below is my exting envelop

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2019-11-28T08:18:33.396Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2019-11-28T08:23:33.396Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <ViewUserResponse xmlns="urn:myapp-com:Security.2014.pop.service.operation1">
            <ViewUserResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <LoginID xmlns:a="urn:myapp-com:Security.2012.pop.service.operation2">

                    <a:IDType>
                        <a:ID>pop</a:ID>
                        <a:Type>UserName</a:Type>
                    </a:IDType>
                    <a:IDType>
                        <a:ID>pop@we.com</a:ID>
                        <a:Type>email</a:Type>
                    </a:IDType>
                </LoginID>
                <Address xmlns:a="urn:myapp-com:Security.2012.pop.service.operation2">
                    <a:City>MH</a:City>
                    <a:State>IND</a:State>
                    <a:Pincode>1234</a:Pincode>
                </Address>
                  .
                  .
                  .
```

I try to replace the LoginID part with a new content the new content is

```
                    <a:IDType>
                        <a:ID>pop_new</a:ID>
                        <a:Type>UserName</a:Type>
                    </a:IDType>
                    <a:IDType>
                        <a:ID>pop_new@we.com</a:ID>
                        <a:Type>email</a:Type>
                    </a:IDType>
```

Below is my code

```
def g = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(newXml).declareNamespace(a:'urn:myapp-com:Security.2012.pop.service.operation2');

    existingXml.LoginID.replaceBody(g)
```

This throws an error 
***org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 137; The prefix "a" for element "a:IDType" is not bound.***

Answer (score 0):

I can't guess why you have the error because you are not sharing the full code.

But you could set the values of the tags without using `replaceBody`

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText('''
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Body>
        <ViewUserResponse xmlns="urn:myapp-com:Security.2014.pop.service.operation1">
            <ViewUserResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <LoginID xmlns:a="urn:myapp-com:Security.2012.pop.service.operation2">
                    <a:IDType>
                        <a:ID>pop</a:ID>
                        <a:Type>UserName</a:Type>
                    </a:IDType>
                    <a:IDType>
                        <a:ID>pop@we.com</a:ID>
                        <a:Type>email</a:Type>
                    </a:IDType>
                </LoginID>
            </ViewUserResult>
        </ViewUserResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
''')

xml.'*:Body'.'*:ViewUserResponse'.'*:ViewUserResult'.'*:LoginID'.'*'.find{it.'*:Type'.text()=='UserName'}.'*:ID'[0].value='rock'
xml.'*:Body'.'*:ViewUserResponse'.'*:ViewUserResult'.'*:LoginID'.'*'.find{it.'*:Type'.text()=='email'}.'*:ID'[0].value='rock@we.com'

groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

returns

```xml
...
        <LoginID>
          <a:IDType xmlns:a="urn:myapp-com:Security.2012.pop.service.operation2">
            <a:ID>rock</a:ID>
            <a:Type>UserName</a:Type>
          </a:IDType>
          <a:IDType xmlns:a="urn:myapp-com:Security.2012.pop.service.operation2">
            <a:ID>rock@we.com</a:ID>
            <a:Type>email</a:Type>
          </a:IDType>
        </LoginID>
...
```